# remote implementing c++ program through php

Tags: php, c++

Recently I've been working on web page based remote control. the function is already there done by c++ and now I'm trying to find a way linking this function to my web page.
I tried using soap and now almost give up because of those "cannot load wsdl file" and "http get method not implemented" errors

Is there any other way to do this beside using soap?
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Do you really want to use PHP?

You can also put the webpage stuff in the C++ application and make it a (fast)cgi application or by using a framework like [wt](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [CppCMS](http://cppcms.sourceforge.net/wikipp/en/page/main)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds rather general so here are some possible directions:

- Bind C++ to a custom php module
- Call C++ binary with php system('')
- Maintain a control socket (TCP / UDP /...) in C++ Daemon and connect from PHP
- Integrate C++ in other Application Framework than PHP (.Net, ...)

As for the soap errors, what did you use to wrap your C++ into a SOAP Provider?